# How to limit multiple input fields (which use v-model) to only accept numbers in Vue.js (without repeating code for every input field)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, vuejs2, v-model

I have multiple  input fields and I want to **limit them to accept numbers only** in Vue.js. 
***I want do disable user from typing any characters except digits from 0-9.***
I already did that successfully by doing this(this solution **copy-paste proof**):

Code in Vue.js template:

`<input type="text" name="priceMax" class="input" @input="correctNumberInput" />`

Method that removes everything except numbers:

```
correctNumberInput: function(event){   
          event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
        }
```

This worked perfectly fine on multiple fields.

***Here comes the problem:*** For different reason, I needed to use ***v-model*** on these input fields. After adding ***v-model*** my method doesn't work anymore. I guess it's because v-model also uses input event under the hood. So only adding "v-model", stops it from working:

`<input type="text" name="priceMax" class="input" @input="correctNumberInput" v-model="priceMax" />`

I have few possible solutions in mind, but all of them include a lot of repeated code.

For example, I could add watchers for every input field, but that would be a lot of repeated code (because I would need to do it for every input field). I have 5 input fields, so basically I would need to write 5 almost identical watchers. I would like to avoid that if that is possible... For example:

```
watch:{
   number(){
      this.priceMax = this.priceMax.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
   }
}
```

Is there any way I can solve it and make it as simple as my solution was ***without repeating code***? **It would be nice to also have solution that is copy-paste proof.** All suggestions are welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566430/vue-js-how-to-restrict-special-characters-in-an-input-field) will help

Comment: Thanks for answer! These solutions are good, but the biggest problem for me is repeating of code. I have 5 input fields, so basically I would need to write 5 almost identical watchers. I would like to avoid that if that is possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to test some code. Here what I have ([link to the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-allen-mt7ls?file=/src/components/MyInput.vue)):

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="priceMin"
        class="input"
        v-model="priceMin"
        @input="correctNumberInput"
      >
      <label v-html="priceMin"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="priceMax"
        class="input"
        v-model="priceMax"
        @input="correctNumberInput"
      >
      <label v-html="priceMax"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MyInput",
  data: () => {
    return {
      priceMin: "",
      priceMax: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    correctNumberInput: function(event, data) {
      const name = event.target.name;
      let value = String(this[name]).replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
      if (value) {
        this[name] = parseInt(value, 10);
      } else {
        this[name] = "";
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

This is the code:

```js
correctNumberInput: function(event, data) {
  const name = event.target.name;
  let value = String(this[name]).replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
  if (value) {
    this[name] = parseInt(value, 10);
  } else {
    this[name] = "";
  }
}
```

So I used your function, but I am not changing the `event.target.value`, I am changing the `data`. So I need to know the name of that data, that's why I use `name` attribute from input fields (`const name = event.target.name;`)

**Update**

If we have `input type=number`, then it has strange (empty) value inside `@input` callback. So it seems, better use keyboard filter ([example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-cannon-nyjnb?file=/src/components/MyInput.vue)):

The main idea to have keyboard filter:

```js
filterDigitKeys: function(event) {
  const code = window.Event ? event.which : event.keyCode;
  const isSpecial =
    code === 37 ||
    code === 39 ||
    code === 8 ||
    code === 46 ||
    code === 35 ||
    code === 36;
  const isDigit = code >= 48 && code <= 57;
  const isKeypad = code >= 96 && code <= 105;
  if (!isSpecial && !isDigit && !isKeypad) {
    // if not number or special (arrows, delete, home, end)
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

And attach it to inputs:

```html
<input type="number" min="0" name="numberInput" class="input"
    v-model.number="numberInput" @keydown="filterDigitKeys">
```

Note: if we keep only `@keydown` handler, then we will not filter text insert into our inputs (but ctrl+v is not working anyway, only by mouse).

Comment: Thank you very very much! This is the solution I was looking for! Very clever and elegant.  I just didn't know how to do it this way, because I am beginner in Vue.js and I didn't know about usage of "[]" with "this". I definitely learned something new through your answer! Thanks again!

Comment: @VasilijeBursac this is not from Vue, this is from JS itself. Any object is actually a map, so `a.b` and `a['b']` works the same.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that it's the same thing. Thank you for amazing explanation!

Comment: Sorry if I bother you, but do you know why this code doesn't work for number input fields? If you try to type "e", "-" etc in number input field, it still shows that in field, it doesnt't replace that with "" (empty string). I don't understand why it doesn't work, because I used the same function on number fields before and it worked perfectly. Check out code with added number field: [example with added number input field](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-fire-fbr9r?file=/src/components/MyInput.vue)

Comment: @VasilijeBursac I've added Update to my answer. Check it

Comment: Thanks for answer, that is definitely a good point! Basically, it had empty value inside @input callback and inside property in "data", but field wasn't empty. What solved problem for me is adding `event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");` before `let value = String(this[name]).replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");`.This just made sure that we filtered and cleared the field, too. I understand that this isn't the best solution, so I will try yours, too! Thanks for everything Anton. Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```html
<input type="number" name="priceMax" class="input" @input="correctNumberInput" v-model.number="priceMax" />
```

From that site: [click](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number).

Comment: Thanks for answer! Unfortunately, this one doesn't help, because I want do disable user from typing any characters except digits from 0-9 and your solution will only typecast 
user input from String to Number.